# Subtle List<string> Manipulation

Tags: c#

I have two `List<string>` (`listOfFullPaths` containg full database paths for e.g. "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase.mdf") and some other `List<string>` containing *some* of the names of the databases (only) ('listOfDatabases'). So each might include

```
List<string> listOfFullPaths = new List<string>() 
{
    "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase1.mdf",
    "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase2.mdf",
    "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase3.mdf"
};
```

the other just

```
List<string> listOfFullPaths = new List<string>() 
{
    "SomeDatabase1",
    "SomeDatabase2"
};
```

My question is **what is the most efficent way of returning the full paths contined in `listOfFullPaths` that have their corresponding database in `listOfDatabases`?**

Note: The answer is *not* something like

```
List<string> tmpList = new List<string>();
foreach (string database in listOfDatabases)
    if (listOfFullPaths.Contains(database))
        tmpList.Add(database);
listOfFullPaths.Clear();
listOfFullPaths = tmpList;
```

although this does what I want.

Comment: That seems pretty straight-forward to me.  What exactly is your criteria for rejecting the solution you have shown in your question?

Comment: Efficient in what manner? Execution time or implementation time? How many items do you have in your lists?

Comment: Yeah I concur with @Boo, your solution works just fine for your `List` scenario. There is no magic one or two lined way of doing with without iteration.

Comment: I could have thousands so I want the most efficent in terms of memory and execution time.

Comment: I would at least use `.EndsWith(database + ".mdf")` to avoid false-positives like checking "SomeDatabase1" and "SomeDatabase10" or part of the directory path, or at least some efficient way of handling these corner cases.

Comment: Have you tried Linq Intersect?  Any way you skin it, you'll be looping through both multiple times, whether in your code or lower level.  Unless your list is incredibly long, in the range of thousands, I can't see how the code you provided isn't good enough.

Comment: I presumed there might be some secret .NET hero, that could resue me from my afternoon of programming mysery...

Comment: @Killercam don't fix something that isn't broken.

Comment: @BrianGraham good advice I will remove the question unless someone wants some sneeky rep...

Comment: If you wre asking about path handling functions, then `System.IO.Path` has sevral functions to make this easier, such as `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)`

Comment: Would it be more if he created his own comparer and used that? Something similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it efficiently in terms of speed (i.e. in O(n)) then JaredPar's answer is correct.
Here is a more idiomatic version:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(listOfDbs);
List<string> result = listOfFullPaths
    .Where(p => set.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're rejecting the nested loop due to performance concern?  If so then another way to approach this problem is the following.

```
var set = new Set<string>(listOfDatabases);
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (string fullPath in listOfFullPaths) {
  var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
  if (set.Contains(name)) {
    list.Add(fullPath);
  }
}
listOfFullPaths = list;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var fileNames = listOfFullpaths.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x));
listOfFullPaths = listofDatabases.Where(x => fileNames.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Note that if you know in advance that the `listOfFullPaths` is sorted by the database name, you can make it much more efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd create a FileInfo.  I'm not 100% on the internals of the FileInfo, but it would have to read from the disk for its information, removing efficiency.

Comment: @ThinkingSites I've replaced that with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)`, which does not access the disc at all. I've tested. It only performs string manipulation logic.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you want maximal efficiency you create a dictionary or hashed set with the database name as a key off the bat.

```
var listOfFullPaths = new List<string>() 
{
    "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase1.mdf",
    "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase2.mdf",
    "C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase3.mdf"
}.ToDictionary(k => Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(k));
```

Then you can loop through listOfDBs and look for the hash

```
listOfDbs.Where(w => listOfFullPaths.Contains(w));
```

In this case, you do two loops and take advantage of the built in indexing of the dictionary.

Comment: This wastes a lot of memory where not needed, for he doesn't really need full indexing, just whether a database exists once or not.

Comment: He's posing a no-win situation.  You either lose memory efficiency or performance efficiency, for no real reason. Myself, I'd stick with the answer he had if it works.

Comment: contrary to popular belief, you cannot always optimize for both memory and processing time; since the question already has the solution optimized for memory, I think this answer deserves its spot.

Comment: Good point. Removed -1. Suggesting to lose the lists if have a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both lists are populated, and you don't have access to the file on disk, then this linq will help you.

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> listOfFullPaths = new List<string>() 
{
    @"C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase1.mdf",
    @"C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase2.mdf",
    @"C:\MyDir\SomeDir\SomeDatabase3.mdf"
};

List<string> listOfDatabases = new List<string>() 
{
    "SomeDatabase1",
    "SomeDatabase2"
};

var dbs =  from path in listOfFullPaths
           from db in listOfDatabases
           where System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) == db
           select path;
```

Comment: @Yorye Especially if you're doing thousands.